# How do I render data immediately after it was created

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I am created a comment section where i would like to be able to create a comment and immediately after display it in the comment section but i am not sure how to rerender the jsx after state changes. putting the state in the useEffect dependency creates an infinite loop. Help would be appreciated.

```
const Post = (props) => {

    const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
    const {id} = useParams();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        fetchComments();
    }, [])

    const fetchData = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:1234/api/posts/${id}`).then((res) => {
            setPost(res.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    const fetchComments = () => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:1234/api/posts/${id}/comments`).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            setComments(res.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }


    console.log(comments)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>thumbnail image</div>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <div>this is where body of post will go</div>
            <CommentForm postId={post._id}/>
            {comments.map((comment) => (
                <Comment comment={comment.comment} username={comment.author.username} time={comment.timeStamp}/>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: please show your attempt to create the comment.

Comment: I am able to create comments but inorder for it to render on to the screen i have to reload the page

Comment: i still need to reload for the new comment to render.

Comment: What's the process at the moment? Are you creating a comment in the form component, the form component uploads the comment to the server, and... you're hoping that the comment will somehow appear?

Comment: You'll need to show the comment creation for actual help since the component you've shown is solely concerned with display. A common pattern is swr (see: [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) for one implementation) which allows for display of stale data while updates are checked for either through explicit invalidation, or via polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you're creating a comment, it can vary. One rule of thumb when updating state, in the case of arrays as is the case with objects, you should treat them as immutable types. For example, if you're updating the comments with `setComments`, opt for `setComments([...comments, newComment])` -- using the spread syntax, or `concat` is preferred as it forces the return of a new object. Since `useState` for object types is based on the reference, this approach will force a re-render on append.

Answer (score 0):

Update the comments array with the new comment and setComments to this new object. The component will re-render automatically.